# How to determine if next 3 days has weekend?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far this is what I have done. But the output is different for what I am expecting for except for the 3rd sample but it only display the `+1 date` not the whole date.

```js
var datess = new Date();
var ndate = new Date(datess.getDate() + 1);
var ndate2 = datess.getDate() + 1;


document.getElementById("newdate").innerHTML = datess;
document.getElementById("newdate1").innerHTML = ndate;
document.getElementById("newdate2").innerHTML = ndate2;
```

```html
<div id = "newdate">

</div>
<div id = "newdate1">

</div>
<div id = "newdate2">

</div>
```

What I want to achieve on this is after determining if it has a weekend it will pass into a `variable` and that variable will be use in loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var afterTomorrow = new Date(tomorrow.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);


document.getElementById("newdate").innerHTML = today;
document.getElementById("newdate1").innerHTML = tomorrow;
document.getElementById("newdate2").innerHTML = afterTomorrow;

//getDay() return day number
//0 - Sunday
//1 - Monday
//2 - Tuesday
//...
if (tomorrow.getDay() == 0) {
  console.log("Tomorrow is sunday !");
} else if (tomorrow.getDay() == 6) {
  console.log("Tomorrow is Saturday !");
}
//Do same with after tomorrow
```

```html
<div id="newdate"></div>
<div id="newdate1"></div>
<div id="newdate2"></div>
```

Comment: Does this explain anything?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It does what OP was trying to do

Comment: @Weedoze yes. But can i ask why using time? not date?

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw This is the way to get tomorrow full date

Comment: @Weedoze thanks. I will think about how can I use this method in my loop code.

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw No problem ! Glad that it helped you !

Comment: @Weedoze I know it does, but I am asking an explanation of it. Do you understand? We are not machines, while the askers are not machines as well. You need to explain what you have done, why have you done. Else you are just depleting the chance of the OP to learn.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I understand

Comment: @Weedoze lastly. For example date today is `14` +3 days = `date 17` How to pass a value of 1 in a variable?. because between date 14 and 17 has weekend right?

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw I don't understand what you need

Comment: @Weedoze can you make a chatroom if your not busy?. If busy then its okay i will to research it :)

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw Sorry I am a little busy for the moment... You can try to ask another question on SO or do some research ! Good luck

Answer (score 8):

The first thing we need to know is, the weekends consists of the dates:

```
0 - Sunday
6 - Saturday
```

Now, we need to check if the next three days contain this. Possible values are from Wednesday. So, you need to check:

```
if (dateObj.getDay() >= 3)
  return true;
```

You don't need to check for others because, the range is `0 - 6` and this code covers everything. Even if you give Sunday, which has a value of `0`, it says `false` as Monday is not a weekend.

```html
<input type="date" id="dtobj" placeholder="Enter a Date" />
<button onclick="if ((new Date(dtobj.value)).getDay() >= 3) alert('Weekend!'); else alert('No Weekend!');">Check</button>
```

The above code works perfectly fine in Chrome. Please note that this `Date` is relative to the client machine and not the server.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var datess = new Date();
var ndate = new Date(datess.getTime() + 86400 * 1000);
var ndate2 = new Date(datess.getTime() + 86400 * 2 * 1000);

document.getElementById("newdate").innerHTML = datess + check_weekend(datess);
document.getElementById("newdate1").innerHTML = ndate + check_weekend(ndate);
document.getElementById("newdate2").innerHTML = ndate2 + check_weekend(ndate2);

function check_weekend(t) {
    if (t.getDay() == 0 || t.getDay() == 6) {
        return "(Yes)";
    } else {
        return "(No)"
    }
}
```

```html
<div id = "newdate">

</div>
<div id = "newdate1">

</div>
<div id = "newdate2">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at Date Methods.

You cannot add +1 to a Date, you need to use it's "get"/"set" methods.

```
var d = new Date()
d.getFullYear()   // 2016
d.getMonth()   // 9
d.getDate()   // 11
```

If you use `d.getDay()` it will return the day of the week, and this is what you need to find weekends.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var DayToCheck = new Date();
if (DayToCheck.getDay() == 6 || DayToCheck.getDay() == 0) alert('DayToCheck is weekend!');
```